# Type alias for inferred type

Tags: scala

I have a method with a complicated return type and I would like to have a function which takes the result of this method as a parameter. Is it possible to create an alias for the return type of the method? Something like typeof from C++

e.g.

```
object Obj {
    def method(x:Int) = 1 to x
    type ReturnType = ???

    //possible solution if i know a parameter for which the method won't fail
    val x = method(1)
    type ReturnType = x.type

    //another possible solution, I don't need a parameter that won't fail 
    //the method but i still think there is a better way
    lazy val x = method(1)
    type ReturnType = x.type

    //I would then like to have a function which takes ReturnType as a parameter
    def doit(t:ReturnType) = Unit
}
```

The thing is that the compiler knows the type but I don't know how to get it from him.

Comment: To my knowledge it is called *dependent types*.

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ scala plugin, you can check type of any expression or method using `Alt`+`=`. In Scala REPL, you can get type of any expression with `:type` command.

Comment: @ghik Yeah, I know I can find the type in an IDE or in REPL, but in my case the complete type is over 80 characters long and having it in the source code would not help readability. Also it is possible that the return type will change in the future.

Comment: @om-nom-nom dependent types in the traditional sense is a type which varies depending on the value: eg a list in which a list of length 1 has a different type then a list of length 2. This doesn't sound like what the OP wants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could think of is this:

```
class Return[T](f:() => T) {
  type Type = T
}

def getDifficultReturnType() = 1 to 10

val Return = new Return(getDifficultReturnType)

def doIt(t:Return.Type) = {

}
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is indeed more comprehensible than my solution. Thank you. What I'm curious about is why doesn't the FunctionN trait have that type alias? (I know I could create an implicit conversion, but is there any particular reason why the return type should not concern me?)

Comment: In most cases it's not what you would want. I would have typed the `doIt` method with a `trait` or `structural type` that contains the features I will use in that method. If I wanted to preserve the original type I would add a type parameter like this: `def doIt[T <: TraitOrStructuralType](t:T)`. An application contains a lot of functions, it would be a bit of a waist to add a type alias on all of them.

Comment: I considered the structural type, but the desired behavior is not really simple either (the ReturnType in my case is the type of a result of a slick query doing a join of multiple tables) In any case thank you, this is indeed a nicer way to do what I wanted. Although I will try to think if it is really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is not possible. Perhaps in a future Scala version with [type macros](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/typemacros.html).

In any case, leaving the type away if it's non-trivial is not a good design in my opinion. I understand that you don't want to type 80 characters, but if it's crucial to preserve that type (as it sounds), it should be explicated at *some* point.

You can use a *type alias*:

```
object Obj {
  type ReturnType = My with Very[LongAndComplicated] with Name
  // explicit type ensures you really get what you want:
  def method(x: Int): ReturnType = 1 to x  

  def doit(t: ReturnType) {}
}
```

Comment: Well, it _is_ possible (via the lazy val and nulls for the method parameters). It just isn't nice. The thing with writing the whole type is that I don't think it would help anyone to see it written out (the body of the method is a rather complicated slick query which results in a type which I don't even understand - I was thinking about using structural type to define what I require from the result type but that seemed like a lot of work for no particular benefit). Anyways thanks for the input, if it indeed is not possible otherwise, I'll write the type out.

Comment: @MartinKolinek I think you are mistaken. What you are doing is using the dependent type `x.type` for _some value generated from the method_. This is not the general return type of that method. Just try calling `doit` with another value obtained from `method`, and you will see that it is not possible.

Comment: Initially I thought so too, but given method `def method(x:Int):List[Int] = throw new Exception()` the lazy val approach works. In other words the lazy val is not evaluated by the  `x.type` code.